# How to replace a fixed date with dynamic date in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

```
select concat(CURRENT_DATE, ' ', '00:00:00+02:00')
```

returns `"2020-07-14 00:00:00+02:00"`

I can copy-paste this result into my `WHERE` clause:

```
where (xyz between timestamp with time zone '2020-06-01 00:00:00+02:00' 
and timestamp with time ZONE 2020-07-14 00:00:00+02:00
```

and it works, but if I use a more dynamic construct `concat(CURRENT_DATE, ' ', '00:00:00+02:00')` instead:

```
where (xyz between timestamp with time zone '2020-06-01 00:00:00+02:00' 
and timestamp with time ZONE concat(CURRENT_DATE, ' ', '00:00:00+02:00')
```

I get a syntax error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "concat" LINE 57: ...6-01 00:00:00+02:00' and timestamp with time ZONE concat(CUR...

Why the first WHERE clause works, but not the other, even though it's printing the same date in same format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`at time zone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT):

```
where xyz between ('2020-06-01'::date at time zone '+02:00') and (current_date at time zone '+02:00')
```

Comment: doesn't work: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "at" LINE 57: ...xyz between '2020-06-01'::date at time zo...`

Comment: @van_folmert . . . These work (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=44de7a1a592968af82deaaed4e0ecf77).  What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: @van_folmert . . . Oops.  Because of precedence, the expressions need parentheses used like this.